# Excepción 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' c# cuando intento correr mi programa

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de hacer un programa que lea y se pueda escribir en un archivo csv en c# pero cuando lo ejecuto me da el error System.IndexOutOfRangeException, dejo parte de mi codigo para saber que en lo que fallo, ya intente resolverlo pero simpre me da el mismo error

```
    static void leerCSV()
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\h\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SM20065.csv"));
        List<String> lista = new List<string>();
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var linea = reader.ReadLine();
            var valores = linea.Split(',');
            for (int i = 0; i < valores.Length; i++)
            {
                if ((i % 7) == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(valores[i] + ',' + valores[i + 1] + ',' + valores[i + 2] + ',' + valores[i + 3] + ',' + valores[i + 4] + ',' + valores[i + 5] + ',' + valores[i + 6]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bievenido a SOes. Revisa [ask] para ver como mejorar tu pregunta. De ser posible, comparte el stacktrace completo de tu error para saber donde está ocurriendo, además siempre es preferible que pegues texto a un pantallazo (que por cierto, no se distingue nada, revisa la imagen que subiste).

Comment: la imagen del stacktrace es muy pequeña

Comment: Está clarisimo que cuando la variable `i` tome un valor multiplo de 7 y el tamaño de arreglo `valores` menos el valor de `i` sea menor de 7, la sentencia siguiente `valores[i+6]` dará el error  `System.IndexOutOfRangeException`. Eejmplo: Si el tamaño de arreglo `valores`  es 15, cuando `i` tome valor 14, i % 7=0, por tanto se cumple la condición  `(i % 7) == 0` y la linea siguiente generará no uno si no varios errores de indice fuera de rango; `valores[14+1]` es `valores[15]`; `valores[14+6]` es `valores[20]`, indices fuera de rango, ya que el rango de los indices posibles es entre cero y 14.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es porque en cada iteración del ciclo `for` que sea múltiplo de `7` intentas referenciar las siguientes 6 posiciones sin validar si exceden la longitud del arreglo.

Un ejemplo para ilustrar el problema:

Suponemos que `valores.Length` es igual a `8`.
Hay que tener en cuenta que el primer elemento de un arreglo está en la posición 0 por esta razón solo podemos referenciar las posiciones del 0 al 7.

Esto quiere decir que en la iteración `7` del ciclo `for` ya estarías en el máximo elemento que se puede referenciar.

Con el escenario descrito, ocurre lo siguiente con tu código:

```
//                |                  | Aquí se produce el error
//                | elemento         | porque el arreglo no tiene elemento 8   
//                |                  | 
//                V  i = 7           V  i+1 = 8 
Console.WriteLine(valores[i] + ',' + valores[i + 1] + ',' + valores[i + 2] + ',' + valores[i + 3] + ',' + valores[i + 4] + ',' + valores[i + 5] + ',' + valores[i + 6]);
```